# Linking to docx on site running IIS 6 is presented as zip file in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-6, mime-types

On our site we have links to several docx files. This file format is in fact compressed xml, but should present itself as a Word document when clicked. It all works fine in FF and Chrome, but not in IE8 and earlier. We've added the following MIME type for docx:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

This has been done both on the site and on the computer in IIS, but to no avail. We've recycled the app pool, restarted the site, and run iisreset a bunch of times. Whatever we do it just does not seem to go right. Somehow IE8 thinks this file is a compressed file and insists on running it as one. The server is a 2003 R3 SP2 Windows server.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use mime type application/msword or even application/octet-stream

Its technically not correct, but it will work.